# assigning value of nested json property to another complex json object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to assign each field of a javascript object to another object's fields: like

Object1:

```
[{
  'field1': 'somevalue'
}, {
  'field2': 'somevalue'
}, {
  'field3': [{
      'field3_1': 'somevalue'
    },
    {
      'field3_2': 'somevalue'
    }
  ]
}]
```

Object 2

my Another object is like

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value 3",
    "field4": "value4",
    "field4": value5,
}
```

How can I achieve in javascript? When I tried something like below:

```
object1.field1=object2.field1
object1.field3.field3_1=object2.field3
```

I get ReferenceError: field1 is not defined

Expected output:

```
{
            ‘field1’: value1
        },
        {
            ‘field2’: value2
        },
        {
            ‘field3’: [
                {
                    ‘field3_1’: value3
                },
                {
                    ‘field3_2’: value4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]’}’
```

Comment: Try using straight quotes, not "smart" quotes (which are invalid syntax)

Comment: Yeah I tried. Above example is just a sample. My json is more complex

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is an undeclared object value5 it might be a string then you must put "". Then you can you following method

```js
let object1={};
let object2 ={
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value 3",
    "field4": "value4",
    "field4": "value5",
};

object1.field1 =object2.field1;
object1.field3=[];
object1.field3.field3_1=object2.field3
console.log(object1);
```

Without declaring parent object you cannot assign values. I hope this is what you looking for.